# Permission denied (publickey) outside home directory

Tags: permissions

I need to use git from a directory located in Desktop. When I use `ssh <url>` it gives

```
no such identity: .ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
Permission denied (publickey)
```

However, I can connect to the server if I shh from home directory.
How I can update ./ssh to make it accessible from any directory?

Comment: What command are you using to connect by ssh?

Comment: I want to run : git push origin master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem like you may have made an error when setting up git to use the ssh keys. The error would be using the path `.ssh/id_rsa` when really you needed `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, which will tell the `ssh-agent` to look in the `.ssh` directory in your home directory. Currently it will be searching for the `.ssh` directory in the current directory, which is why it works when you're in the home directory.

Assuming that you set up your ssh keys in a manner similar to [the github tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/), you'll need to remove your faulty configuration from the `ssh-agent`, and add the key with the correct path.

To remove the incorrect key, while in your home directory:

```
ssh-add -d .ssh/id_rsa
```

Add the key with the correct path:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The key should now be available from any directory.

Comment: Hi Arronical. Your answer was super helpful for me.  I did as you mentioned, I also update the .ssh/config file and set (IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa). Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked. You can accept the answer and upvote it with the check and the upwards arrow on the left hand side if you like.